# Registry For All Users

Tags: c#, wix, registry, installation, wix3.5

I create a `per machine` installer for a dll.

The registry is created properly under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

The class definition under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is creates only for the user who installed the program. The rest of the users on the same machine are missing this registry.

From this my conclusion id thata the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is individual per user.
Where is the registry that keeps the classes data for all users?

EDIT : This is how I define the COM registry for the local machine:

```
<Class Id="{1AF5E2B9-CC02-368F-A879-1DF3F538D71A}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="AdminAddins.MyClass" ThreadingModel="both" ForeignServer="mscoree.dll">
        <ProgId Id="AdminAddins.MyClass" Description="AdminAddins.MyClass" />
</Class>  

<File Id="fil08256E64C10A4B2F5423A768ECB9A473" Name="AdminAddins.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\AdminAddins\bin\Release\AdminAddins.dll" />

<RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{1AF5E2B9-CC02-368F-A879-1DF3F538D71A}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45e7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}" Value="" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{1AF5E2B9-CC02-368F-A879-1DF3F538D71A}\InprocServer32\1.0.5300.19297" Name="Class" Value="AdminAddins.MyClass" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{1AF5E2B9-CC02-368F-A879-1DF3F538D71A}\InprocServer32\1.0.5300.19297" Name="Assembly" Value="AdminAddins, Version=1.0.5300.19297, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{1AF5E2B9-CC02-368F-A879-1DF3F538D71A}\InprocServer32\1.0.5300.19297" Name="RuntimeVersion" Value="v2.0.50727" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{1AF5E2B9-CC02-368F-A879-1DF3F538D71A}\InprocServer32\1.0.5300.19297" Name="CodeBase" Value="file:///[#fil08256E64C10A4B2F5423A768ECB9A473]" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{1AF5E2B9-CC02-368F-A879-1DF3F538D71A}\InprocServer32" Name="Class" Value="AdminAddins.MyClass" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{1AF5E2B9-CC02-368F-A879-1DF3F538D71A}\InprocServer32" Name="Assembly" Value="AdminAddins, Version=1.0.5300.19297, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{1AF5E2B9-CC02-368F-A879-1DF3F538D71A}\InprocServer32" Name="RuntimeVersion" Value="v2.0.50727" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{1AF5E2B9-CC02-368F-A879-1DF3F538D71A}\InprocServer32" Name="CodeBase" Value="file:///[#fil08256E64C10A4B2F5423A768ECB9A473]" Type="string" Action="write" />
```

Comment: Notice that it should go into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID`, not `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\CLSID`.

Comment: @Chris, I get a compilation error: `Error LGHT0204: ICE03: Invalid registry path; Table: Registry, Column: Key, Key(s): regD7AE136AD9ADD38B38F6FD34732C93E2` Any ideas?

Comment: How does the line giving you that error look?

Comment: @Chris, I solved the problem by deleting the '\' character before the registry path. **The results:** The class GUID is registered under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID` as expected, but the class itself is not registered to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes`. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know much about Windows Installer. Is it supposed to create those keys by itself?

Comment: @Chris, Thanks, There is no explicit way to refer the class element to the `HKLM` as it seems. Isn't there?

Comment: If you just manually add the <RegistryValue>'s you need to the xml, will Windows Installer accept it?

Comment: @Chris, I found the answer - following your instructions and than adding a property `ALLUSERS = 1` register the classs for all of the users. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Class registration and file name extension information is stored under both the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and HKEY_CURRENT_USER keys. The HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes key contains default settings that can apply to all users on the local computer.
>
> The HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes key contains settings that apply only to the interactive user. The HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key provides a view of the registry that merges the information from these two sources. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT also provides this merged view for applications designed for previous versions of Windows.

This looks useful too:

> To change the default settings, store the changes under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes. If you write keys to a key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, the system stores the information under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes. If you write values to a key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, and the key already exists under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes, the system will store the information there instead of under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. Please see my update in post. Any ideas?